# How to convert predicates to SQL statement?

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I am encountering a problem in my iOS app happening after 3 days of gathering data from server. I'm trying to pinpoint the problem and don't know if its a data corruption problem or a problem in the code.

I have downloaded the iOS database to my Mac and can run sql statements against it.

Is there a way to "convert" the following predicates to SQL statement so that I can verify the data?

```
    NSMutableArray *predicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDate *twoWeeksago = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                                           value:-14
                                                                          toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                         options:0];
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isRemoved == 0"]];
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(publicationDatetime >= %@) AND (publicationDatetime <= %@)", twoWeeksago, [NSDate date]]];
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(source == %@) OR (source == %@)", @"BBC", @"Guardian"]];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
```

Comment: Do you still require assistance with this?

Comment: Sure, it would be good to know for future :)

Comment: See my answer below. I really hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so a bit of a shot in the dark here as i don't know what it's doing wrong for you and my Objective C and predicate knowledge is limited but i think what you are ending up with is this:

```
where removed = 0
  and (publicationDatetime >= 2weeksAgo) AND (publicationDatetime <= today)
  and (source = 'BBC') OR (source = 'Guardian')
```

Now where i think it might be giving you unexpected results is in the OR portion. What it's basically saying is that it's going to bring back records that meet:

```
removed = 0
(publicationDatetime >= 2weeksAgo)
(publicationDatetime <= today)
(source = 'BBC')

OR

(source = 'Guardian')
```

What i think you need to change is this:

```
(source = 'BBC') OR (source = 'Guardian')
```

to this:

```
((source = 'BBC') OR (source = 'Guardian'))
```

Putting those into another set of brackets means all the other conditions must be met and either one of 'BBC' or 'Guardian'  must also be met.

Comment: Thanks, I accept for the time being, until I can test it fully.